# How do you interpret thresholds in CLMM (intercepts and odds ratio)

Tags: r

How do you express and interpret CLMM thresholds? Preferably using Odds ratio. Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Some background info: I have done a survey of human perceptions towards an animal. I used a CLMM to analyze the data with perception (1, 2, 3) as my response variable. My predictors are education, gender, experience of crop-raiding and observation of the animal. Village (where the survey was performed) as a random effect. Using package: "ordinal", https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf

Now im in the process of interpreting the results of the CLMM. I would like to use sjplot and analyze results based on odds ratio, but I'm having issues understanding the thresholds. Eg: 1|2 comes out with an estimate of -1.0375 and an odds ratio of 0.35. The sjplot also signifies that the odds ratio has a significant p-value (figure of sjplot below). What does this threshold odds ratio mean?

```
Xclmm <- clmm(OrdinalPercept ~ Education + Gender + Crop_raid + Obs + (1|IDVillage), Data = HR, Hess = TRUE, threshold = c( "flexible"))

summary(Xclmm)
```

[Coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TLCN.png)

Am I right in this interpretation of the estimates?

Threshold coefficient estimate:

1|2         -1.0375
2|3         0.3724

```
1 < -1.0375
2 > -1.0375 and < 0.3724 (-1.0376 to 0.3723)
3 > 0.3724
```

Respondent of gender female (estimate = 0.783) is expected to be in the third group ((3), estimate > 0.3724). And female respondents have 2.19 (odds ratio) times the odds of men, being in that third group (perception group 3).

What does the odds ratio of 1|2 and 2|3 mean?

[Sjplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dSDx.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: As this is an interpretation issue, and not a coding issue, please post on Cross Validated here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. New post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524211/how-do-you-interpret-thresholds-in-clmm-intercepts-and-odds-ratio